# How to migrate a question to another site?

Tags: discussion

I've seen more and more questions that get migrated from other SE sites over to here. I think that's cool to do.

But how can we migrate a question to another SE site? I mean this one is obviously not really about wordpress and has been closed therefore:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5881/how-can-you-edit-all-permalinks-in-blogengine-net-closed

But as it was already migrated from webapps over to here, I think we should give it back instead of closing it. But I have not idea how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is now possible for moderators to perform arbitrary site-to-site migrations via the moderator menu. However

- it is frowned upon to migrate to sites still in beta
- obviously, you should only migrate appropriate questions and this one was not appropriate

I'll follow up with that moderator... I assume this was an accident.

In the meantime I deleted both.

Comment: Thanks for getting on the issue. I mean this can happen, in the question the term wordpress appeared and it's not always easy to find out about scope.

Comment: I was the one who saw the question had been migrated from webapps and I migrated again to SO because it wasn't appropriate here and it seems most appropriate on SO because of SO's .NET focus. Did I do something wrong?  What should I have done?

Answer (score 3):

Migration option appears when you vote to close post and choose `off topic` as a reason. Migration paths seems to be established manually and only path I seen from us is to our meta.

I think I've read that no sites going to be migration targets until they graduate beta, so it's slightly strange we started to get these incoming questions.